# Controlling the sound during a Keynote presentation

Tags: mac, audio

Cómo puedo controlar el sonido insertado durante la presentación. No puedo ver el icono y no lo puedo controlar. Tampoco me permite aumentar el tamaño del icono. El Keynote 6 6.1 no me lo permite. 
Gracias,

Google Translate:
How I can control the sound inserted during the presentation. I can not see the icon and I can not control. Nor can I increase the size of the icon. The Keynote 6 6.1 will not let me. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Las teclas de acceso rápido aún deben trabajar en Keynote. Puede utilizar F10 - F11 - F12 ( tal vez añadiendo la tecla Fn si es necesario ) para ajustar el volumen.

Translated:

The hotkeys should still work in Keynote. You can use F10 - F11 - F12 (perhaps adding the Fn key if necessary) to adjust the volume.